# empty data from Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

The data variable returns nothing when it should return "OK" or "EXISTS".

I have a template with an overlay effect. The income.html template has a form and a button "Add a new category", when you click on it a new window is displayed(overlay effect) with a tiny form.

income.html:

```
(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#new_cat").live("click", ( function() {      
    var cat_name = $("#nc").val();
    if (cat_name) {
        $.get("/cashflow/new_cat/0/", { name: cat_name, account: "{{ account }}" },
          function(data){
            if (data == "OK") {
                $("#id_category").val(cat_name);
            }
            if (data == "EXISTS") {
                var error = "The category already exists";
                alert(error);
            }
          });
    }
    else {
         var error = "Please enter a name";
         alert(error);
    }
}))  
});
</script>
...

<form>{% csrf_token %}
       <label for="name">Name:</label><input type="text" id="nc" />
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="new_cat" />
</form>
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
def income(request, account_name): 
    account = account_name
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TransForm(user=request.user, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            income = form.save(commit=False)
            income.type = 0
            income.account = Account.objects.get(
                            name = account_name,
                            user = request.user)
            income.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            income.category = form.cleaned_data['category']
            income.save()
            uri = ("/cashflow/account/%s") % str(account_name)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(uri)

    else:
        form = TransForm(user=request.user)

    context = {
          'TransForm': form,
          'type': '0',
          'account': account, 
    }
    return render_to_response(
        'cashflow/income.html',
        context,
        context_instance = RequestContext(request),
    )

def new_cat(request, type):
    if request.method == u'GET':
        GET = request.GET
        if GET.has_key(u'name'):
            name = request.GET[u'name']
            account = request.GET[u'account']
            c = Category.objects.filter(name=name, account=account)
            if c:
                s = "EXISTS"
            else:
                c = Category(name = name, user = request.user, 
                        type = type, account = account)
                c.save()
                s = "OK"

    return HttpResponse(s)
```

Edit: Debug info

```
> ../cashflow/views.py(765)new_cat()-><django....xa507b0c>
-> return HttpResponse(message)
(Pdb) p message
'EXISTS'
(Pdb) n
> ../site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py(112)get_response()
-> if response is None:
 p response.content
'EXISTS'
(Pdb) p response.status_code
200
```

A weird thing is that when I want to debug, the overlays show while debugging, not after. That's why I think it's a JS error. I forgot to tell that the category is created and saved properly to the db.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the AJAX call is working corerectly?  Add an error handler to the `$.get`.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Or an overall AJAX error handler:

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked for javascript errors?

It looks to me like  `{{ account }}` is `account_name` in the view, and if the name means anything it's most likely a string.

In your ajax template, you supply `{{ account }}` directly with no quotes so it should throw a javascript error for being undefined.

Also, in this situation, I would always debug a little more in your ajax call. Throw in a pdb.set_trace() and see what the code is doing when you send the request. Where is it dying?

You can literally walk through the code as it checks the `GET`, looks for key `account`, Whether it is ever making it to defining variable `s`.

Comment: I fixed the error and forgot to modify it in the post. You're right it was throwing a javascript error. I debugged the view called from the ajax function and all the view is executed fine.

Comment: The view can't be working fine if it's returning nothing! What does a browser debugger show you in XHR as the server response? No error message? You sure you're not getting an error message but **nothing** ? For example, CSRF would be a problem with this view unless you have it disabled.

Comment: The first step is to find out if this is JS or Django. Do the ajax call, and tell us what you see in the ajax response from a browser debugger.

Comment: I think it's a JS error, I edited my initial post with more info.

Comment: OK, nice debug there -- the view is definitely executing correctly. How about the actual response? (JS debugger) What does it see? What IS variable `data` ?